# Pandas add new column depending of 2 columns from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes like these:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame([1,10,'a'],[11,15,'b'],[16,25,'c'],[26,27,'a']], columns = ['Start','End','Val'])
df
   Start  End Val
0      1   10   a
1     11   15   b
2     16   25   c
3     26   27   a

df_2 = pd.DataFrame([2],[12],[15],[23]], columns = ['Time'])
df_2
   Time
0     2
1    12
2    15
3    23
```

And want to add a new column to `df_2` with values from `df_1['Val']` if `df_2['Time']` is between `df_1['Start']` and `df_2['End']` (inclusive). The resulting `df_2` would be:

```
df_2
   Time Value
0     2     a
1    12     b
2    15     b
3    23     c
```

What is the best way to do such operation with pandas?